# Capacitor C6 dislodged

Tags: hardware, power-supply, electronics

I managed to break the C6 capacitor on Raspberry Pi Model B. Its the 220uF 16V EE6 capacitor. Nobody seems to have such low capacitance, low voltage capacitor (the least I can find is 220uF and 60V). Any suggestions or hacks? I found one

http://roevalley.com/newsbrowser/pi_projects/powpi.htm

but this is a not sufficiently clear on the specs of the components used. I don't want to fry the pi unwittingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of this capacitor should not be critical, it filters the supply voltage. In general, a larger capacitance is better. The voltage is not critical either, as long as it's rated above 5V (but some margin may be nice). A higher voltage rating should not hurt, but merely give you a larger and more expensive capacitor. 
Have a look at the [schematic](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Raspberry-Pi-Schematics-R1.0.pdf), your cap is connected between ground and the input voltage. The input voltage is directly wired to several places (test point 1, the GPIO pins, the other USB ports), so if your new cap doesn't fit where the old one was, maybe you can put it somewhere else. Then you don't have to hunt for a cap with the right footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Mine snapped off as well. With only moderate soldering skills, I was able to solder it back into place fairly easily, and it has worked fine since. I held it in place with a pair of needle-nose pliers while heating the pads and tabs on the capacitor with the soldering iron.

After repairing it, I put the Pi into a proper plastic [case](http://www.adafruit.com/products/975) to prevent repeating the damage.

This [article](http://raspberrypisquared.com/you-may-have-the-capacity/) may help for instructions, and also has a link to the replacement part. The same part can be ordered from [Newark](http://www.newark.com/panasonic/eee-fc1c221ap/capacitor-alum-elec-220uf-16v-20/dp/12M9811?Ntt=EEEFC1C221AP) in the U.S.

Answer (score -1):

check out dipmicro. 220uF/16V Radial Electrolytic Capacitor - 
http://www.dipmicro.com/store/C8E22-16.C